# OPENDATASOURCE for reading excel

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2005, import, oledb

I am tryng to import excel data from using following SQL statement :

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * 
              INTO ##tempExcelData1
              FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source=' + @filePath + ';Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=yes;"'')...[Sheet1$]'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

But the larger strings are not imported fully ...Its reading first 255 characters only..
But My excel sheet may have larger strings..anybody can help me in this?

Comment: Can't you put the file in a path with a shorter name?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu where should i put?

Comment: Usually on a Path with the least number of characters. If you have access to C:\ then you can put it there.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu that i already put...executed this query.. When I do  select * from ##tempExcelData , I am getting the rows..but only few characters of longer length rows